# How to create the Kygo Pluck?

Tags: music, synthesizer

I searched for help so long! I really want to know how to make the exact same lead sound in any synthesizer as it can be heard at 1: 15

Please help me! I have no idea how to start (I am pretty good at producing I would say but not in sound design)

You would make my day!!!

Answer (score 1):

The majority of sound design in the electronic genres are simply applying ADSR envelopes to the volume and the filter cut-off of a synth.

This sound (and all other nice electro plucks) are ALL about the ADSR envelope controlling the filter cutoff of a low pass filter.

Any pluck starts with this starting point, and then just gets tweaked from there.

- First put the low pass cut off at midway starting point.
- then put the routing/control of the ADSR env generator the influence the low pas filter about +50%. This control is usually at mid point/neutral. So midpoint = 0%
- then put said ADSR envelope attack=0% decay=25% sustain=0% release=0%

Once those are set from there, the three parameters you want to tweak to modify the sound are  Low Pass cuttoff , ADSR decay time, and env to filter control.

What about the oscilator that we are filtering? Well for this particular synth, it is either a square wave or more likely a series of sin waves at octaves - which is essentially a a square wave with less overtones.

This is with 100% certainty the method used for this kygo pluck. Just tweak those 3 parameters and play with the oscilator type.

Comment: If it does don't forget to flag it as an answer. Also try using TyrellN6 freeware synth.